# What is the SASS way called for DRY'ing something like this up, if there is one --> .content p, .content ul, .content li, .content a?

Tags: css, sass, css-selectors

What is the SASS way called for DRY'ing something like this up:

```
.content p, .content ul, .content li, .content a
```

Comment: Is you intention to target all paragraphs, unordered lists, and links? Or you real intention is to select elements that share some common quality? Most of the time it is 2), and it makes more sense to assign class to all such elements. Plus, what happens if you decide to change <ul> to <ol> in the future? Or <p> to <section>?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

All 4 of those elements have styles in common?

```
.content {
    p, ul, li, a {
        // styles they all share
    }
}
```